# Converting String to Date in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a `timestamp` in my big query looking like this: `30/01/2020 00:14:05`

`date` is one of the column names of the table

I have already tried:

```
1. cast(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) as DATE)
2. CAST(date as DATE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need `SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S','30/01/2020 00:14:05')`

or `SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',SUBSTR('30/01/2020 00:14:05',1,10))` if you only need the date

Comment: You are correct you have to parse it to datetime first, but converting from datetime to date is can be done without the substr
`SELECT DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '30/01/2020 00:14:05'))`

Comment: I used `parse_date()` with `substr()`, not `parse_datetime()`

Comment: DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y',SUBSTR(date,1,10)),WEEK) this worked for me. Thank you @MartinWeitzmann and Georges